# Why Does .addEventListener() Not Work When .onClick() Does?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js file that I import into the index.html. In the js file I create buttons dynamically according to another button click.

```
  var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
        removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
        removeButton.setAttribute(
          "onClick",
          'remove("' + ann + '","' + lastid + '")'
        );
```

But the **remove function** only works if I put it in   in the index file. If I do

```
removeButton.addEventListener("click",function(e){
          remove(ann,lastid)
        })
```

and define remove **in the js file**, it gives me this error when I click on the button:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

The remove function:

```
function remove(ann, id) {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var item = document.getElementById(id);
    list.removeChild(item); // this gives error
   ....
  }
};
```

Any idea why?

EDIT: added lastid, defined list (copy/paste error, sorry)

Comment: In the remove function, `list` is not defined. That is the cause of the error methinks

Comment: Make sure `last` is defined... the working version uses `lastid`

Comment: are you using jquery here ?